# Asyncio: keep multiple coroutines running

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have multiple coroutines which need to be running (forever) at the same time. For error handling one of the routines occasionally ends and needs to be respawned and I use the following code, which however assumes that it is coroutine1 that needs restarting.

```
pending = {coroutine1(), coroutine2()}
while True:
    a = asyncio.wait(pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    done, pending = loop.run_until_complete(a)
    pending = pending | {coroutine1()}
```

How can I solve this in a better and more general way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a different approach?

```
async def run_forever(corofn):
    while True:
        await corofn()

corofns = coroutine1, coroutine2
await asyncio.wait(map(run_forever, corofns))
```